# Android GCM IntentService loop "doing some work"?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Cloud Messaging in an Android app and I was wondering what is the purpose of this part of the code in the IntentService, once the GCM message has been received and before processing:

```
// This loop represents the service doing some work.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (D) Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
   try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Any thoughts about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you removed it? Does it has any impact on code? Please reply ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I removed it.
It is a useless chunk of code to serve as an example of the app's running some task to manage the received message.

Comment: Ok thanks I too removed n update app.hey can u please tell me how to sending gcm message in batches of 1000? I m using app engine java language.

Comment: I've always sent them through my own backend, so I can customize it in the exact way I want, I cannot help you there but it shouldn't be too hard, a bit of googling will do, good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the code from, but it looks like it doesn't have any purpose other than illustrating that the IntentService might perform some processing that takes a substantial amount of time. Hence the loop and the Thread.sleep.

Comment: It's an Android Developers sample.
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive

I was wondering that maybe it was to prevent the phone from doing too much work in case many messages arrived at the same time from the GCM server.

Comment: @Alqueraf "// This loop represents the service doing some work." this comment says it all. It has no actual meaning.

Comment: So you mean it is useless and I can remove it? Sorry for being repetitive but since the Android Devs put it there I thought it might have some functionality that I don't understand.

Comment: @Alqueraf yes, you can remove it.  The comment tells you what's it for.